# Encoding the dynamicaly-typed lambda calculus in Haskell using recursive types

Tags: haskell, types, functional-programming, lambda-calculus

I'm reading Pierce's Types and Programming Languages book and in the chapter about recursive types he mentions that they can be used to encode the dynamic lambda calculus in a typed language. As an exercise, I'm trying to write that encoding in Haskell but I can't get it to pass the typechecker:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes, ScopedTypeVariables #-}

data D = D (forall x . x -> x )

lam :: (D -> D) -> D
--lam f = D f
lam = undefined

ap :: D -> D -> D
ap (D f) x = f x

--Some examples:
myConst :: D
myConst = lam (\x -> lam (\y -> x))

flippedAp :: D
flippedAp = lam (\x -> lam (\f -> ap f x))
```

Right now, this code gives me the following error message (that I don't really understand):

```
dyn.hs:6:11:
    Couldn't match type `x' with `D'
      `x' is a rigid type variable bound by
          a type expected by the context: x -> x at dyn.hs:6:9
    Expected type: x -> x
      Actual type: D -> D
    In the first argument of `D', namely `f'
    In the expression: D f
    In an equation for `lam': lam f = D f
```

Changing the definition of `lam` to undefined (the commented-out line) gets the code to compile so I suspect that whatever I did wrong is either on lam's definition or in the original definition for the D datatype.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this doesn't work is because `f :: D -> D`. `D` wants a function which can take in any type `x` and return `x`. This is equivalent to

```
d :: forall a. a -> a
```

As you can see, the only sane implementation for this is `id`. Try

```
 data D = D (D -> D)
 ...
 unit = D id
```

Perhaps for better printing:

```
 data D = DFunc (D -> D) | DNumber Int
```

Comment: Damn its so obvious now. In Haskell the recursive type quantifier is implicit so I didn't need to try to write it down like I did.

Answer (score 2):

The issue is that your `f` has type `D -> D` (according to your type signature for `lam`), but the `D` constructor expects an argument of type `forall x . x -> x`.  Those are not the same type, so the compiler complains